# How to Install Act Framework on Mac

Tags: actframework

I have installed java and configured the path and Trying to use Intellij IDE. 
But how to install act framework and get started? There is no detailed installation guide on the website!

Comment: Welcome to the community please familiarize yourself with the following: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask This is not a question for Stackoverflow. Make sure to search on Google or slack communities within your tech stack for help finding installation documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to "install" actframework, just like you don't install [springframework](https://spring.io/). However you can start your project skeleton using maven archetype, which is documented in the very beginning of [README](https://github.com/actframework/actframework/blob/master/README.md) file of actframework project at github:

```
mvn archetype:generate -B \
    -DgroupId=com.mycom.helloworld \
    -DartifactId=helloworld \
    -DarchetypeGroupId=org.actframework \
    -DarchetypeArtifactId=archetype-quickstart \
    -DarchetypeVersion=1.8.28.0
```

Comment: Then what about dependeny jars. How to use the act libraries without having them on our system

Comment: The maven automatically imports dependencies from Central Repository- Todays learnings.  
Act works perfectly well and i am happy to join act world